# How to filter posts by tags using django-taggit in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-taggit

Currently, I'm still learning with Django and creating my blog using Django 2.2. but somehow there's an error when I using django-taggit.

How to filter the post by tags?

I've read the documentation but there's not fully covered about how to implement this into a real project.

Here's my code:

I've tried several different ways that I'm still searching from StackOverflow but still doesn't have an answer.

The results from `/blog/tag/post-tagged` is the same from `/blog`.
So how do I filter it from `views.py`? or perhaps from `blog.html`?.

So the result of `/blog/tag/post-tagged` is only from the tagged post.

here's my code:

`models.py`:

```py
...

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager



"Post Model"
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
...
```

`views.py`:

```py
def blogIndex(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created_date")[0:4]
    context = {"posts": posts,}
    return render(request, 'blog.html',  context)



def Tagging(request, slug):

    tags = Tag.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-tags")

    context = {
        'tags': tags,
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)
```

`urls.py`:

```py
path("tag/<slug:slug>/", views.Tagging, name='tagged'),
```

my `blog.html`:

```html
<div id="tags-middle">
   <div class="tags-cloud">
      Tags :
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
         <a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this issue by filtering the tags from `views.py`.

Since I have multiple tags in my posts. so the `__in` and `tags` must be **in the list**.

Here's my `views.py`:

```py
tags = Tag.objects.filter(slug=slug).values_list('name', flat=True)
posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tags)
```

Basically, as the [documentation](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit) said that we can filter by using string just like:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["Lorem"])
```

But it only takes one string.

if I try by using multiple strings like `["Lorem", "Ipsum"]` it will show me only a blank page on `/blog/tag/lorem`.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal blog, i'm doing the following to filter the posts by a tag:

in the `urls.py`:

```
...
path('tag/<tag>', views.tag, name='tag'),
...
```

the `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
...
def tag(request, tag):
    "This page shows all posts with the related tag"
    
     posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)
     return render(request, 'blog/tag.html', {'tag': tag, 'posts': posts})
```

With this you can have a `blog/tag.html` template something like:

```
<h2>List of posts of the tag "{{ tag }}"</h2>

{% if posts %}

<ul>

{% for post in posts %}

// displays whatever you want about the post

{% endfor %}

</ul>

{% else %}

<p>No post related to that tag yet.</p>

{% endif%}
```